# How to decode character entity references

Tags: javascript, encoding

I know `unescape` can convert `%u6F22%u5B57` to 漢字:

```
unescape("%u6F22%u5B57");
```

But how can I convert `&#x6F22;&#x5B57;` to 漢字？

If someone can provide hints, I'll be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
var input = "&#x6F22;&#x5B57;";
return unescape(input.replace(/&#x(\w{4});/g, '%u$1'));
```

Comment: Thanks, to tell the truth, since I'm new here and didn't know what to do after solved.

Answer (score 0):

In a browser, you can have the document do the work:

```
var element = document.createElement('span');
element.innerHTML = '&#x6F22;&#x5B57;';
return element.textContent;
```